# Is there a way to rename the derived field name in Local Transformations when using SVM in R with scale=TRUE (default)

Tags: r, svm, pmml

On using e1071 package, SVM Classification with Iris dataset. I see the model/pmml generated with scale=TRUE always normalizes the dataset attributes with names like algorithm_derived_nc_. Is there a way where I can specify specific name say "attr1_foo" to be given instead of default name.

```
library(pmml)
library(e1071)
svmModel<-svm(Species~.,data=iris)
pmml(svmModel)

shows..
<PMML...>
..
<Output>
   <OutputField name="Predicted_Species" feature="predictedValue"/>
  </Output>
  <LocalTransformations>
   <DerivedField name="algorithm_derived_nc_Sepal.Length" dataType="double" optype="continuous">
    <NormContinuous field="Sepal.Length">
     <LinearNorm orig="0" norm="-7.05660228803556"/>
     <LinearNorm orig="5.84333333333333" norm="0"/>
    </NormContinuous>
   </DerivedField>
...

</PMML>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to `pmml` package source code, the names of derived field are hard-coded:

```
dfName <- paste("algorithm_derived_nc_",inputNames[i],sep="")
```

Why is the naming of `DerivedField` elements a problem at all? Their scope is limited to the body of the `SupportVectorMachineModel` element, so the end user does not see or have to care about them ever.

You can always post-process the result PMML files with XML or plain text manipulation tools. For example, it would be straightforward to replace "algorithm_derived_nc_" with "adn_" (or whatever else feels appropriate).

Comment: ok..Thx for the inputs..Yes besides post processing..pmmltransformation and xformInfo can also be leveraged.